# How to inject <script> tag into empty iframe without document.write?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to load an `iframe` that does nothing else than load a JavaScript file from a given URL. While this would be easy by loading a simple HTML page into the iframe that only contains the `<script>` tag to load the JavaScript file, but that would require two requests to the server.

So my idea is to write the code to load the JS file from the calling method in the parent window into the empty iframe.

Something like this works on all browsers:

```
function createScriptFrame(container, url) {
    const frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    container.appendChild(frame);
    const doc = frame.contentDocument;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('<html><body><script src="' + url + '"></script></body></html>');
    doc.close();
}
```

But using `document.write` is a really nasty way of doing it. Chrome even complains with a warning in the console: *[Violation] Avoid using document.write().*

I've come up with a few alternative approaches, for example:

```
// same as above until doc.open()
const s = doc.createElement('script');
s.src = url;
doc.head.appendChild(s);
```

or

```
const s = doc.createElement('script');
s.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('(function() { const s = 
document.createElement("script"); s.src = "' + url + '"; 
document.body.appendChild(s); })()'));
doc.head.appendChild(s);
```

These work nicely in Chrome and Safari but **not in Firefox**.

I've compiled a test with several methods to load the script: https://embed.plnkr.co/l8DwUBQs7cQsi938eTOn/

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a blob and open it

```
var url = 'foo'
var blob = new Blob([
  '<html><body><script src="' + url + '"></script></body></html>'
], {type: 'text/html'})
var iframeUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
console.log(iframeUrl)
```

...Or if you like a base64 url

You can also use the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) but it isn't supported by IE/Edge

Comment: Nice idea, I've added both blob and data URL to the Plunk, but neither works in any browser. The frame content is properly created but the `frame.js` is never loaded. Could be a security constraint.

Comment: you must add the `base` tag or use absolute path to your javascript file

Comment: there is one different between blob and dataURI in that blobs will inherit the Origin property which can be important for accessing the same local storage, cookies, indexeddb, cors-request etc

Comment: Using the absolute URL worked for both data URL and blob. Thanks! Still need to find out about browser support...

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls with android you might have to use webkit prefix

Comment: don't forget to revokeObjectURL if you don't need it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.write()` you could now use a new attribute on iframe which is `srcDoc`.

https://caniuse.com/iframe-srcdoc